# multiple knitr kables by group

Tags: knitr, r-markdown

for a given dataset, I want to print group-wise kables with group names as caption in an rmarkdown.

say this is my_document:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  slice(1:10) %>% 
  do(kables = kable(., caption = .$Species[1])) %$%
  kables %>% 
  lapply(print)
```

i call `rmarkdown::render("my_document.R")` to generate the markdown output.

the problem now is that my kables appear in comments, but not as rendered kables:

```
## Table: setosa
## 
##  Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width   Petal.Length   Petal.Width  Species 
## -------------  ------------  -------------  ------------  --------
##           5.1           3.5            1.4           0.2  setosa  
##           4.9           3.0            1.4           0.2  setosa  
##           4.7           3.2            1.3           0.2  setosa  
##           4.6           3.1            1.5           0.2  setosa  
##           5.0           3.6            1.4           0.2  setosa  
##           5.4           3.9            1.7           0.4  setosa  
##           4.6           3.4            1.4           0.3  setosa  
##           5.0           3.4            1.5           0.2  setosa  
##           4.4           2.9            1.4           0.2  setosa  
##           4.9           3.1            1.5           0.1  setosa  
## 
## 
## Table: versicolor
## 
##  Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width   Petal.Length   Petal.Width  Species    
## -------------  ------------  -------------  ------------  -----------
##           7.0           3.2            4.7           1.4  versicolor 
##           6.4           3.2            4.5           1.5  versicolor 
##           6.9           3.1            4.9           1.5  versicolor 
##           5.5           2.3            4.0           1.3  versicolor 
##           6.5           2.8            4.6           1.5  versicolor 
##           5.7           2.8            4.5           1.3  versicolor 
##           6.3           3.3            4.7           1.6  versicolor 
##           4.9           2.4            3.3           1.0  versicolor 
##           6.6           2.9            4.6           1.3  versicolor 
##           5.2           2.7            3.9           1.4  versicolor 
## 
## 
## Table: virginica
## 
##  Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width   Petal.Length   Petal.Width  Species   
## -------------  ------------  -------------  ------------  ----------
##           6.3           3.3            6.0           2.5  virginica 
##           5.8           2.7            5.1           1.9  virginica 
##           7.1           3.0            5.9           2.1  virginica 
##           6.3           2.9            5.6           1.8  virginica 
##           6.5           3.0            5.8           2.2  virginica 
##           7.6           3.0            6.6           2.1  virginica 
##           4.9           2.5            4.5           1.7  virginica 
##           7.3           2.9            6.3           1.8  virginica 
##           6.7           2.5            5.8           1.8  virginica 
##           7.2           3.6            6.1           2.5  virginica
```

so how do i get rendered kables by group in my markdown document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `results="asis"` in the chunk options. Have a read of http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#chunk_options as you may also want to use `echo=FALSE` to hide your code and/or `message=FALSE` to hide any messages that arise from loading packages.

E.g., if I don't specify `message=FALSE` I get:

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

```
The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

in the final output after loading dplyr.

Comment: thanks, this works in a .Rmd where I can specify chunk options. but in my case I explicitly want echo all figures and tables from a plain .R script and I do so using the notebook option in RStudio (which I guess interprets the .R file as a single-chunk .Rmd file). So is there a way to give global knitr options to the rendering process?